# Sort jQuery Result By Attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Is it possible to sort a jQuery result by an attribute's value? For example, consider the following code snippet and result:

```js
$('span').each(function()
{
    $('#log').append($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span name="a5"></span>
<span name="a3"></span>
<span name="a6"></span>
<span name="a1"></span>
<span name="a4"></span>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Without modifying the HTML or DOM, how can I best modify this code to get a sorted result, ie. *a1a3a4a5a6*? Though I could obviously stick each result in an array and then sort it afterwards, I'm assuming there's a more elegant way using jQuery's native abilities. Is there?

Comment: http://trentrichardson.com/2013/12/16/sort-dom-elements-jquery/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to build intermediate array, jQuery exposes [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method for convenience:

```
$.fn.sort = Array.prototype.sort;
```

and since `Array.prototype.sort;` is generic <sup>(</sup>*****<sup>)</sup> it just magically works with jQuery collections too.

```js
$('span')
.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return $(a).attr('name').localeCompare($(b).attr('name')); 
})
.each(function() {
    $('#log').append($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span name="a5"></span>
<span name="a3"></span>
<span name="a6"></span>
<span name="a1"></span>
<span name="a4"></span>

<div id="log"></div>
```

---

<sub>***** Generic in context of prototype methods means that methods internal implementation does not care about `this` instance being a real `Array` instance, as soon as it's an [array-like collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Working_with_array-like_objects).</sub>

Comment: Not sure you want to use `localeCompare` here. If you change `<span name="a5">` to `<span name="a59">` the resultant order is `a1a3a4a59a6` when it should probably be `a1a3a4a6a59`. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0n3rayLj/

Comment: here's a quickie: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yrmao2k9/. Might need to double check it.

Comment: Yes, something like this.. However I'm not sure wether OP would really have such attributes or it was just an example and real situation would want  `localeCompare` comparisons. Plus if attributes are `aX`, `bX`, ... sorting part becomes more complex.

Comment: +j0891 is right about localeCompare not being good for numeric values, so I'll definitely watch out for that. However, this answer put me on the right track. Thanks guys!

Comment: Best way to sort in my opinion is probably `parseInt($(a).attr('name'), 16) - parseInt($(b).attr('name'), 16)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
var $names = $('span');
var $log = $('#log');

$names.sort(function(a,b){
    var aProp = a.getAttribute('name'),
        bProp = b.getAttribute('name');

    if (aProp > bProp){
        return 1;
    }

    if (aProp < bProp){
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});

$names.appendTo($log);
```